# how to load all saved docker images in parallel

Tags: docker, parallel-processing, load

I have 20 images TARed, now I want to load those images on another system. However, loading itself is taking 30 to 40 minutes. All images are independent of each other so all images loading should happen in parallel,  I believe.
I tried solution like running load command in background(&) and `wait` till loading finishes, but observed that it is taking even more time. Any help here is highly appreciated.

**Note**:- not sure about the option `-i` to `docker load` command.

Comment: I imagine that would take a lot of memory. Is your server maxing out on memory? You may be able to increase the maximum amount of memory of your docker engine in order to speed things up. I don't imagine you could load all 20 images at a time really efficiently. Maybe sequentially is the best method for you.

Comment: Is it one big tar file or 20 separate ones?  Can you use a Docker registry and `docker pull` instead?

Comment: @arjabbarHow can I increase memory for my docker engine?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```sh
find /path/to/image/archives/ -iname "*.tar" -o -iname "*.tar.xz" |xargs -r -P4 -i docker load -i {}
```

This will load Docker image archives in parallel (adjust `-P4` to the desired number of parallel loads or set to `-P0` for unlimited concurrency).

Answer (score 0):

For speeding up the pulling/saving processes, you can use ideas from the snippet below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEMP_FILE="docker-compose.image.pull.yaml"

image_name()
{
    local name="$1"
    echo "$name" | awk -F '[:/]' '{ print $1 }'
}

pull_images_file_gen()
{
    local from_file="$1"
    cat <<EOF >"$TEMP_FILE"
version: '3.4'
services:
EOF
    while read -r line; do
        cat <<EOF >>"$TEMP_FILE"
    $(image_name "$line"):
        image: $line
EOF
    done < "$from_file"

}

save_images()
{
    local from_file="$1"
    while read -r line; do
        docker save -o /tmp/"$(image_name "$line")".tar "$line"  &>/dev/null & disown;
    done < "$from_file"
}

pull_images_file_gen "images"
docker-compose -f $TEMP_FILE pull
save_images "images"
rm -f $TEMP_FILE
```

images - contains needed Docker images names list line by line.

Good luck!